# editing dynamic menu php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu (with sub menus) in Php and MySql. And trying to build dynamic editor for manipulate with this menu, create , delete and etc. I've stacked when creating menu category with it's position. To understand well take a look at mysql table structure =>

```
create table menu(
id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
sort_id UNSIGNED BIGINT NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
etc ...);
```

I'm sorting menu categories with sort_id, and during creating I gave this column different values (for first time, by default) , because after creating another categories , I'm adding values by 1 and subtracting by 1 too , but I think it is pretty bad way doing it. Any ideas how to manage MySql table to define position of created categories (which would be forward or backward) ? thanks :)

Comment: In sort_id, just put the id of the parent menu, and put 0/-1 in the roots menus. (depending on how your sql manager starts the ids.

Comment: and what about the main menu category which doesn't have any parent menu ?

Comment: please give me a little example , I can not understand well , thanks beforehand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the sort_id as @Jerska said because then you won't be able to sort your submenus & it will complicate/confuse your program logic. You can have a table like this instead

```
CREATE TABLE menu(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  parent_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES menu(id),
  sort_id INT,
  title VARCHAR(100)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

if the parent_id is set to null then it is a root menu.

---

This is an example menu for you:

Home & Garden
- Living Room
- Dining Room
- Bathroom
- Bedroom
- Garden & Conservatory
Electricals
- Sound & Vision
- Computing & Phones
- Home Appliances
- Small Appliances

It would be stored like this:

```
INSERT INTO menu
  (parent_id, sort_id, title)
VALUES
  (null, 1, "Home & Garden"),
  (null, 2, "Electricals"),
  (1, 1, "Living Room"),
  (1, 2, "Dining Room"),
  (1, 3, "Bathroom"),
  (1, 4, "Bedroom"),
  (1, 5, "Garden & Conservatory"),
  (2, 1, "Sound & Vision"),
  (2, 4, "Small Appliances"),
  (2, 3, "Home Appliances"),
  (2, 2, "Computing & Phones");
```

If you actually inserted them in that order, the ID of "Home & Garden" would be 1, and the ID of "Electricals" would be 2 (don't confuse with the sort_id) and the ID of "Living Room" would be 3, the ID of "Dining Room" would be 4... since we're auto-incrementing on the ID field.

So if you want to have a sub-category say in Sound & Vision, first you would find the ID, in this case it would be `8` and then you would add new records with the parent ID as `8`.

Example sub-sub-category:

```
Electricals  
- Sound & Vision  
  * Televisions  
  * Audio
```

You would insert these records:

```
INSERT INTO menu
  (parent_id, sort_id, title)
VALUES
  (8, 1, "Televisions"),
  (8, 2, "Audio");
```

Comment: with this kinda table structure can I have multiple sub menus ? I mean only with this table ?

Comment: @Tornike what do you think happens if a menu has a parent_id pointing to another menu which has a parent_id pointing to a menu with parent_id of NULL?

Comment: Well actually, in my mind, sort_id was used as a parent id. And then everything is fine. He can sort on it also.

Comment: I think it is possible , but asked because I'm just new in MySql, and wanted to be sure, that it was possible :)

Comment: @Jerska Yes, but he should ALTER TABLE and add a column rather than use the sort_id which already has its own purpose. The purpose of the sort_id is not to SORT in the way you are saying, but to choose a specific order to display the menu in - which isn't possible when you use it to store the parent menu id

Comment: @Ozzy pls give me an idea how I should position sub categories during creating , I can not understand , I really need it , thanks beforehand

Comment: @Ozzy to say more simple, for example : first I create category named "One", then after that category I create named "Three", then Can I add category between (for instance named "Two") them with this kinda table structure ?

Comment: @Tornike I added an example for you

Answer (score 3):

In sort_id, just put the id of the parent menu, and for the root menus, just put 0/NULL.

Example : (sid = sort_id)

```
id|sid| title
1 | 0 | Menu1
2 | 0 | Menu2
3 | 1 | Submenu1of1
4 | 1 | Submenu2of1
5 | 2 | Submenu1of2
6 | 4 | Subsubmenu1of2of1
```

will refer to :

```
1 : Menu1
    3 : Submenu1of1
    4 : Submenu2of1
        6 : Submenu1of2of1
2 : Menu2
    5 : Submenu1of2
```

Now making the conversion between step 1 and step 2 is your part of the job.
Use recursivity, and you'll be fine. :)